# How to block access to Web API , except from the ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I have a website in IIS say abc.com
Now i also have a asp.net API as virtual application within abc.com

I want to restrict all direct access to the API ,  except from the website.(browsers, postman, fiddler , etc)
Within the API, I tried to detect ip from which the request was made

```
context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Although the above may help detecting client ip , it may do little to help in preventing outside website request to the API

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Does the web site require logons, and did you implement security? Any web service call (to a static method in a existing aspx page, or even a call to a asmx page? if that page is placed in a folder that has security (in web config, as normally dropped in each folder to secure by security groups (roles)), then those web service calls from the browser simple will not work unless the user is logged into the site correctly.

For any web calls that you don't need or want security, place those aspx/asmx pages in such folders without IIS security applied, and no logon will be required to use such pages.

If you don't' have any security setup? Then it going to be rather hard to suggest you want security for the web site when there is no security setup?

So, even a simple basic FBA (the classic security setup) will thus be handled by IIS, and those web service calls can't occur unless the user is already logged in. So, your free to write and setup ajax calls from the client-side page, and you don't even have to worry about security in that client-side JavaScript code if the site has security setup.

If you don't have any security setup or applied to the site, then it quite much suggests that you don't have many options in the way of security choices.